# Input Fn() Python

Tags: python, input

Can the print () function add and save the sum of numbers from the fn () function?

```
def fn(a,b):
    print(a+b)
a = input('Podaj wartość a:')
b = input('Podaj wartosc b:')
print(fn)
```

Comment: `print(fn(a,b))` ? You never called the function and you should return the values as well if you want to use those values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this. If trying to add 2 numbers.

```
def fn(a,b):
    print(a+b)

a = int(input('Podaj wartość a:'))
b = int(input('Podaj wartosc b:'))

fn(a,b)
```

Comment: Unless your python is not should work fine, but the function isn’t necessary and you could ditch it and move the print function to after the two variables of a and b have been defined.

Answer (score 0):

No, print can't do that. If you want to save the result, do this:

```py
def fn(a,b):
    return a+b
a = input('Podaj wartość a:')
b = input('Podaj wartosc b:')
output = fn(a, b)
print(output)
```

The result will be saved in the variable `output`. Finally, you output the variable.